# (UWP) How to access a viewmodel's properties/methods from within a diff. viewmodel?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, uwp

In my MainView I have a MainViewModel that exists for the lifetime of the application.

My MainView has a Frame embedded WITHIN itself.

Each page that gets navigated to from that frame has their own ViewModel (I think that approach is a good pattern?). We will call these ViewModels "SubViewModel"

What is the best approach for accessing the MainViewModel's properties from within the SubViewModel, and vice-versa?

Answer (score 0):

You cant make other ViewModel can get the ViewModels properties/methods.

The good thing to do it is use the message that the SubViewModel can be send or send Message and the ViewModel can deal with the message .

If the ViewModel can deal the SubViewModels message that is say that SubViewModel can get the ViewModels method for it can send a message call the ViewModel to do method and the ViewModel can get the SubViewModels properties for the SubViewModel can send it's properties to ViewModel.

If the SubViewModels can deal the ViewModels message that like the  ViewModel can deal the SubViewModels message the SubViewModels can get the ViewModels  properties.

I think you are finding a framework and I wrote one:https://github.com/lindexi/UWP/blob/master/uwp/src/Framework

There are some framework like MVVMLight and [this](https://github.com/oppqw/NeUWP/tree/master/NeUWP/NeUWP/Library/Framework) ,
 [JP.Utils.UWP](https://github.com/JuniperPhoton/JP.Utils.UWP/tree/dev/JP.Utils.UWP/Framework)

see:https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI

https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism

https://github.com/FantasticFiasco/mvvm-dialogs

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static property to hold the current instance of the MainPageViewModel

```
public static MainPageViewModel Current { get; private set; }

public MainPageViewModel()
{
     Current = this;
}
```

and use it to access its members.

```
MainPageViewModel.Current.MyProperty
```

Comment: Is that a good practice, or just a convenience? Your approach is something I actually thought of, though.

Comment: This approach is used in the UWP samples for content pages to access members from MainPage, like in the [XamlPivot](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/XamlPivot/cs/Scenario1.xaml.cs) sample and [ApplicationResources](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/ApplicationResources/cs/scenario1.xaml.cs). I use it all the time when I need access to a view or a viewmodel from a lower level member, but I don't know if it's the best approach. Would be happy to see if someone has a better solution.